# How to avoid exception of request querystring in vb.net if parameter is not passed

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

If the parameter variable is not passed then this code throws an exception of "Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid."

this is my code.

```
 Public Shared ReadOnly Property Request_projectStartDate() As Date
        Get
            Dim _value As String = Nothing

            If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("projectStartDate") Is Nothing Then
                _value = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("projectStartDate").ToString()
            End If

            Return CDate(_value)
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: sorry i made a mystake the error is "Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid." because it is nothing

Comment: What's your question? `_value_` will be `Nothing` if `projectStartDate` is not on the query string.

Comment: how can avoid this exception? "Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid." Because there is no parameter being passed and the conversion to CDate of nothing throws the exception. Do i need to add a default date there? like 1900/01/01? or is there a way to return nothing ?

Comment: An empty string is not the same as `Nothing`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check what @Massimiliano has reported and one more check

```
If Request.QueryString.HasKeys() Then

   // Check for specified querystrings...
   If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("projectStartDate")) Then
       // Your logic
   End If

End If
```

Comment: the problem is when i convert nothing to cdate actually.

Comment: You dont have to convert nothing into CDate these 2 checks will make sure that there is something (PerojectStartDate) which you can type case by using cdate. are you still getting error?

Comment: thanx. Correct, i don't need to do cdate. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("projectStartDate")) Then
    //
End If
```

Comment: the problem is when i convert nothing to cdate actually.

Answer (score 0):

If Request.QueryString("projectStartDate") IsNot Nothing And Request.QueryString("projectStartDate") <> "" Then